# Passing multiple input data of different sequence length to Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I don't know to structure nested RNN models

I have 3 different table (Assume table name as **table1, table2, table3**)

**table2** is dependant on **table1**, for an entry in **table1** there are multiple entry in **table2**.
similarly **table3** is dependant on **table2**, for an entry in table2 there are multiple entry in **table3**.

for a classification problem,I'm trying to build a neural network model with this dataset.

I'm trying to build a sequence model with table3 data as input (assume model name as **sequence1**),

**sequence1** model passes its output as input to another sequence model that gets table2 data as input(assume model name as **sequence2**),

output of **sequence2** model is again passed as input to a dense model that gets **table1** data as input.

how to structure this model and pass data to it in Keras?.

Comment: Can you provide some code that you have tried? Did you look at google. There would some good tutorials on it.

Comment: Hi @user_3pij , I tried branched neural network architecture. the problem I'm facing is in regards to time stamps.

for a single timestamp of table1 ,there would be n number of time stamps table2 and again for single timestamp of table2 there would be n number of timestamp in table3.

I can't find any tutorial that provides a solution to exponential increase in timestamp for each layer